# How to Store BTsync Data Files in SD Card?

Tags: sd-card, storage, btsync

The new BTsync 2.3 advertises that it has the feature of storing in the SD card of your Android >=5.0. 
However, I cannot find such a setting in Settings of the application. 
There are two options which to do when having the card in CyanogenMod 13 when first time having SD card in the phone: use it as portable SD card or internally. 
I chose using as a portable SD card. 
However, I cannot now see any files in the portable SD card when looking the files with PC.

How can you store BTsync data files in SD card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from the BTsync support

> Did you disable 'Simple mode" in Sync settings -> advanced? If yes, then after scanning a QR code from another peer, to which you want to connect, Sync will ask you to pick folder location, and it's here where you'll be able to pick SD card. Please see detailed guide [here](http://help.getsync.com/hc/en-us/articles/205451165-Syncing-between-a-desktop-computer-and-a-mobile-device).
>
> Else, you can start sharing from the mobile - tap on "=" icon -> add folder and pick a folder from the SD card, share it with other peers. Detailed guide is [here](http://help.getsync.com/hc/en-us/articles/207370636).

where disabling the Simple mode is the trigger to solve my case.
Then Settings > Default folder location and you are able to change to SD card.